# How to get 40 random numbers ranging from 1-10 in java?

Tags: java, random

I've been working on this code to get random numbers. But I only get 1 number. I need 40 numbers. How do I do it?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Random aRandom = new Random();

    System.out.println(aRandom.nextInt(10) + 1);

}
```

Comment: You could use a loop perhaps..

Comment: Go through the basics, SO is not a substitute for a good book, tutorial, class or search-query. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Random aRandom = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++){
    System.out.println(aRandom.nextInt(10) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Java 8:

```
final List<Integer> randoms = new Random().ints(1, 11).
        limit(40).
        boxed().
        collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop forty times over the code you already have and accumulate the results - e.g., in a `List`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Random aRandom = new Random();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(40);

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i) {
        list.add(aRandom.nextInt(10) + 1);
    }

    System.out.println(list);
}
```